# WebStorm - autocomplete React className attribute with quotes instead of object literals

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

WebStorm autocompletes `className=`  into `className={}`  instead of `className=""` as it should.

Is there a way to fix or edit this?

Answer (score 28):

please try changing **Add for JSX attributes:** value in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other** to either **Quotes** or **Based on type** - this should help

Comment: **Based on type** still inserted brackets for `className`. (at least in WebStorm 2022.1.1)

Comment: try using **Quotes** then; is it a reason for downvoating? if you find a better answer (another option to control this), please add it.

Comment: I didn't vote your answer down... I set my **Add for JSX attributes** setting to **None**.

Comment: *Based on type* is inserting quotes in webstorm mac version 2023.3.6